# Printing Non-Linear Linked Lists

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to understand the relationship between Nodes and linked lists. This problem is apart of a bigger program, however, I wish to focus on this specifically. I have a non-linear singly-linked list that looks like this visually:

```
(0,0) <-- (0,1) <-- (0,2) <-- (0, 4) <-- (0,5)

            ^
            |
          (0,3)
```

Where (0,0) is the parent to (0,1). (0,1) is the parent to both (0,2) and (0,3). (0,2) is the parent (0,4), and (0,4) is the parent to (0,5). Each Node has a (row,column) and a reference to the previous node:

```
class Node {
  int x; //row
  int y; //column
  Node previous; // a reference to the previous Node

  Node (int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  Node (int x, int y, int previous) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.previous = previous;
  }

  public Integer getRow() {} //returns x
  public Integer getColumn() {} //returns y
}
```

The main method looks like this:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
  LinkedList<Node> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
  Node head = new Node (0, 0, maze[0][0], null)
  linkedList.add(head);

  Node one = new Node (0, 1, head);
  linkedList.add(one);

  Node two = new Node (0, 2, one);
  linkedList.add(two); 

  Node three = new Node (0, 3, one);
  linkedList.add(three);

  Node four = new Node(0, 4, two);
  linkedList.add(four);

  Node five = new Node (0, 5, four);
  linkedList.add(five);

  for (int i = linkedList.size()-1; i >= 0; i --) {
    System.out.print(linkedList.get(i).getRow() + "," + linkedList.get(i).getColumn());
  }
```

I am trying to print:

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,4) (0,5)
```

But instead, I get:

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) (0,3) (0,4) (0,5)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think there's a bit of a terminology disconnect here. The data structure you have looks more like a [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). Linked lists are basically always a straight chain. As soon as you deal with multiple incoming edges, you have a graph. If you want to trivially get your desired output, skip printing the third node. If you want to do that in a more general way, why not follow the `parent` references until they're null starting from one of the source nodes in the DAG?

Comment: @ggorlen Does this mean within the for loop put an if statement that checks if the next node is null or not?

Comment: Maybe. The data structure you're using doesn't really make sense because it has a `.get` method you're using on the not-shown `linkedList` object, so right now your logical graph structure and its container don't have any obvious relationship. Is the point of all this to find a path through a maze?

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, that is correct

Comment: The "non-linear" linked list you describe is more probably called a "graph" or more specifically a "tree". There are lots of resources online about both of these more general data structures if you are interested in learning more.

Comment: It's not really a tree since there are multiple parents. It's a DAG of nodes stored in a linked list (for some reason). OP, I'd post more about your problem and explain what you're trying to do rather than asking about your solution. From what I can tell, this design doesn't make much sense for solving a maze, so I believe this is an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).